# React Js : Unable to login until page gets refresh manually

Tags: reactjs, express, wampserver

As a beginner to the React Js I'm trying simple projects for hands-on experience and to learn as well! so, in the same way I've created one login portal with react js and WAMP server by watching YouTube tutorial
in the middle I went through some errors but somehow I managed and get them off but after completing the project when I'm trying to login with the credentials which I've given in database the response and all was clear but **the page doesn't redirect to welcome page after clicking on login button** instead it redirects to welcome page after refreshing manually. I couldn't identify the mistake in my code.

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import InputField from './InputField';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton';
import UserStore from './stores/UserStore';


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      buttonDisabled: false
    }
  }

  setInputValue(property, val) {
    val = val.trim();
    if (val.length > 12) {
      return;

    }
    this.setState({
      [property]: val

    })
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.setState({
      username: "",
      password: "",
      buttonDisabled: false


    })
  }

  async doLogin() {
    if (!this.state.username) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.state.password) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: true
    })

    try {
      let res = await fetch('/login', {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password
        })

      });

      let result = await res.json();
      if (result && result.succes) {
        UserStore.isLoggedIn = true;
        UserStore.username = result.username;
      }

      else if (result && result.succes === false) {
        this.resetForm();
        alert(result.msg);


      }


    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.resetForm();

    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="loginForm">
        Log In
        <InputField
          type='text'
          placeholder='Username'
          value={this.state.username ? this.state.username : ''}
          onChange={(val) => this.setInputValue('username', val)}

        />

        <InputField
          type='password'
          placeholder='Password'
          value={this.state.password ? this.state.password : ''}
          onChange={(val) => this.setInputValue('password', val)}

        />

        <SubmitButton
          text='Log In'
          disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled}
          onClick={() => this.doLogin()}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default LoginForm;
```

**SubmitButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';


class SubmitButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="submitButton">
        <button
          className='btn'
          type='submit'
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >

          {this.props.text}


        </button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SubmitButton;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import UserStore from './stores/UserStore';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let res = await fetch('/isLoggedIn', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'


        }
      });

      let result = await res.json();

      if (result && result.success) {

        UserStore.loading = false;
        UserStore.isLoggedIn = true;
        UserStore.username = result.username;
      }

      else {
        UserStore.loading = false;
        UserStore.isLoggedIn = false;

      }


    }
    catch (e) {

      UserStore.loading = false;
      UserStore.isLoggedIn = false;

    }
  }


  async doLogout() {
    try {
      let res = await fetch('/logout', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json'


        }
      });

      let result = await res.json();

      if (result && result.success) {


        UserStore.isLoggedIn = false;
        UserStore.username = '';
      }




    }
    catch (e) {

      console.log(e);

    }
  }



  render() {
    if (UserStore.loading) {
      return (
        <div className="app">
          <div className='container'>
            Loading ,Please Wait...

          </div>

        </div>

      );
    }

    else {

      if (UserStore.isLoggedIn) {

        return (
          <div className="app">
            <div className='container'>
              Welcome {UserStore.username}

              <SubmitButton

                text={'Log Out'}
                disabled={false}
                onClick={() => this.doLogout()}

              />

            </div>
          </div>
        );

      }



      return (
        <div className="app">
          <div className='container'>

            <LoginForm />
          </div>

        </div>
      );

    }
  }
}


export default observer(App);
```

**Router.js**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


class Router {

    constructor(app, db) {
        this.login(app, db);
        this.logout(app, db);
        this.isLoggedIn(app, db);
    }

    login(app, db) {
        app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

            let username = req.body.username; 
            let password = req.body.password; 

            username = username.toLowerCase();

            if (username.length > 12 || password.length > 12) {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'An error occured,please try again'
                })
                return;


            }
            let cols = [username];
            db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username =? LIMIT 1', cols, (err, data, fields) => {

                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        success: false,
                        msg: 'An error occured,please try again'

                    });
                    return;
                }
                if (data && data.length === 1) {
                    bcrypt.compare(password, data[0].password, (bcryptErr, verified) => {
                        if (verified) {
                            req.session.userID = data[0].id;
                            res.json({
                                success: true,
                                username: data[0].username
                            })
                            return;

                        }
                        else {
                            res.json({
                                success: false,
                                msg: 'Invalid Password'
                            })
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        success: false,
                        msg: 'User not Found,please try again..!'
                    })

                }

            });
        });

    }

    logout(app, db) {
        app.post('/logout',(req,res)=>{

            if(req.session.userID){
                req.session.destroy();
                res.json({
                    success:true
                })
                return true;
            }
            else{
                res.json({
                    success:false
                })
                return false;

            }
        })

    }
    isLoggedIn(app, db) {

        app.post('/isLoggedIn',(req,res)=>{

            if(req.session.userID){
                let cols =[req.session.userID];
                db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID=? LIMIT 1',cols,(err,data,fields) =>{

                    if(data && data.length ===1){
                        res.json({
                            success:true,
                            username:data[0].username
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json({
                            success:false
                        });
                    }

                });
            }
            else{
                res.json({
                    success:false
                })
            }

        });



    }

}

module.exports = Router;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change some logic in **LoginForm.js**. There are multiple ways in which you can do that. I am showing you one example.

```
import React from 'react';
import InputField from './InputField';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton';
import UserStore from './stores/UserStore';

import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom' //add a redirect from react-router-dom


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      buttonDisabled: false,
      redirectToRefer : false //add a state here for redirect
    }
  }

  setInputValue(property, val) {
    val = val.trim();
    if (val.length > 12) {
      return;

    }
    this.setState({
      [property]: val

    })
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.setState({
      username: "",
      password: "",
      buttonDisabled: false


    })
  }

  async doLogin() {
    if (!this.state.username) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.state.password) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: true
    })

    try {
      let res = await fetch('/login', {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password
        })

      });

      let result = await res.json();
      if (result && result.succes) {
        UserStore.isLoggedIn = true;
        UserStore.username = result.username;

        this.setState({redirectToRefer:true})//set rediectToRefer as true
      }

      else if (result && result.succes === false) {
        this.resetForm();
        alert(result.msg);


      }


    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.resetForm();

    }
  }


  render() {

    //add a condition at render if redirectToRefer is true then redirect to  your page
      if(redirectToRefer)
        {
           return <Redirect to ="/"/>
        }
    return (
      <div className="loginForm">
        Log In
        <InputField
          type='text'
          placeholder='Username'
          value={this.state.username ? this.state.username : ''}
          onChange={(val) => this.setInputValue('username', val)}

        />

        <InputField
          type='password'
          placeholder='Password'
          value={this.state.password ? this.state.password : ''}
          onChange={(val) => this.setInputValue('password', val)}

        />

        <SubmitButton
          text='Log In'
          disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled}
          onClick={() => this.doLogin()}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default LoginForm;
```